# java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: No route to host?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, driver, sqlexception

```
14:51:34,652 DEBUG [mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool         ] - An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: No route to host: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:436)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:251)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:331)
```

Can anyone tell me:

How can resolve this issue ?

Comment: are you on same network as DB? show ip for your device and the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you get back an [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) "destination host unreachable" message (type 3, code 1).

This means either of those things:

- you don't have a route to the destination host in your routing table (or a router you use doesn't have one);
- a firewall sends this message back to you.

In the first case, fix the route if you can (maybe you have forgotten to initiate a VPN?). In the second case, ask the firewall admin why this occurs (luckily, he/she won't answer you "because yes" but give you a real reason :p)

Comment: @Andres which is equivalent to "you don't have a route to the destination host" ;)

Comment: Yes, it means that; if it were a physical problem, you'd have a connection timeout.

Comment: It depends. i.e. with JPA you'd get a java.net.UnknownHostException.

Comment: Uh great... I don't use JPA but it seems as broken as `File` in this regard (and unlike the new Files API in Java 7 where exceptions make sense at last)

Answer (score 0):

This could occur if you are not connected to the server. Try pinging it to make sure.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I'm not commenting anything. I'm telling him to check his connectivity with the server.

Comment: Then I would rephrase your answer to also include ways of checking connectivity. Otherwise, it sounds like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

check the iptables service is stopped.
"service iptables status"

And verify from your system by the following command,
"telnet server_ip 3306"

ref: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1335778?start=0